# Unable to resolve Preview Load Error in Builder.io

Tags: next.js, builder.io

I started a demo app to test out Builder.io with NextJS app.
I'm getting the "Preview Load Error".
I tried following all the steps provided and looking online, but can't find anything that solves my issue.

Has anyone else run into this issue? What are some common mistakes I could be making?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm still working through how to integrate Builder.io into an existing project.

I was able to get it working by running: 'npm init @builder.io' within the project folder, after I created my NextJS project.